# Type DateTime: bad display

Tags: magento-1.9, datetime

I want to create a grid to display hours from a collection.
So I add the date column like this:

```
    $this->addColumn ( 'date_birthday', array (
            'header' => 'Date of birthday',
            'align' => 'right',
            'width' => '100px',
            'type' => 'datetime'
            'index' => 'mydate'
    ) );
```

In my collection there is: (it's simplified)

1  2017-11-08 18:00:00
2  2011-11-08 12:00:00
3  3017-11-08 10:00:00

The grid displayed is:

1  2017-11-08 19:00:00
2  2011-11-08 13:00:00
3  3017-11-08 11:00:00

With the 'datetime' attributes you can see that all my hours displayed have 1 hour more than the collection.
And without this attributes hours are displayed properly.

Any idea ?
Thanks !

EDIT: I try that but it doesn't works

```
        $this->addColumn ( 'date_birthday', array (
            'header' => 'Date of birthday',
            'align' => 'right',
            'width' => '100px',
            'time' => 'true',
            'type' => 'datetime',
            'format' => Mage::app()->getLocale()->getDateTimeFormat(Mage_Core_Model_Locale::FORMAT_TYPE_MEDIUM),
            'index' => 'mydate'
    ) );
```

Comment: without this attributes hours are displayed properly. ??? What you mean ?? please explain

Comment: if i don't put the attributes 'type' => 'datetime', the hours are displayed properly but it don't have format. If I put  the attributes 'type' => 'datetime' the hour is formatted correctly but there is one hour more than the real hour.

Comment: someone can answer me ??